# Firebase Storage Security Rules - Does the match statement match for strings placed anywhere in a filename?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Accordingly to this section in the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/core-syntax#overlapping_match_statements), these security rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match b/{bucket}/o {
    // Matches any filename containing string '/images/'.
    match /images/{imageId} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }

    // Matches all filenames containing string `/images/`
    match /images/{imageId=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

> All reads and writes to files with the string /images/ **anywhere** in their filename will be allowed because the second rule is always true, even though the first rule is always false.

I understand the naming conventions to emulate a file system and the overlapping stuff... but, does that "anywhere" mean these permissions apply to filenames like `/foo/bar/images/profilePicture.png`? (Just asking because it is strange to me, I supposed rules won't apply to files with another prefix, just supposed they must start with `images`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That actually looks like a mistake in that sample. As far as I know the first `match /images/{imageId}` matches file that are immediately under the `images` filter, while the second `match /images/{imageId=**}` also matches files that are in deeper nested folders under `/images`.